# Use Visual Studio to send PySpark jobs to HDInsight clusters?

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-hdinsight

Not 100% sure whether this is the right stackexchange site for my question, feel free to make move suggestions.

I prefer programming in IDEs (currently mostly using Spyder), but want to make use of a HDInsight Spark cluster by using PySpark. I assumed that Visual Studio supports this, since both are from Microsoft and Visual Studio 2017 can access HDInsight clusters, ADLS, etc., but that does not seem to be the case? Am I missing something?

Closest thing I found was a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/set-up-pyspark-interactive-environment) about doing what I want to do in *Visual Studio Code* - is there really no way to do this in Visual Studio itself (yet?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment only VSCode has native integration with HDInsight for python spark jobs.